# Okhttp android measure TTFB

Tags: android, okhttp

Is there a way to know the Time To First Byte in the OkHttp library? Currently my application measures the total network time which is TTLB (last byte). This is done simply by measuring time before and after the [execute()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.html#execute--) call.

So far I have tried interceptors (https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) but it seems that interceptors cannot server the purpose.

Any pointers or advices will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, further research points me to https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Events
However this is available only since 3.11 release.